# Django how to pass custom error message in class based views

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-class-based-views

I need to be show custom error message for invalid forms. I don't know how to do it in class based views. here is my class based views:

```
class EditPatient(UpdateView):
      model = Patient
      form_class = PatientUpdateFrom
      template_name = 'hospital/edit-patient.html'
      def form_valid(self, form):
        error_message = None
        if form.is_valid():
           name = self.request.POST["patient_name"]
           email = self.request.POST["phone"]
           if len(name) > 20:
               error_message = 'maximum 20 character allowed in name'
           if len(phone) > 20:
               error_message = 'maximum 15 character allowed in phone'
          
           """ #I tried this but didn't work 
           def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                context = super(EditPatient,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
                context['error_message'] = error_message
                return context
           """
          
           if not error_message:
                messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Patient Sucessfully Updated')     
                form.save()
                 
           
           return redirect('hospital:edit-patient',self.object.slug)
```

I know I can do it in forms.py though `raise forms.ValidationError` but I want to know **how to do it in class based views** because I am updating few fields from another model.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `form_invalid` method of your `UpdateView` class:

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
    context.update({"my_message": "Soemthign went wrong"})
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Alternatively, you can make use of [django-braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and use the following mixin: https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form.html#forminvalidmessagemixin

Comment: how to pass my error message  as context in form_invalid?

Comment: I've updated the example to your needs. `my_message` will be part of the context now.

Comment: Does the updated code works for you?

Comment: no didn't work.